# OpenGL problems with ARC (Android apps on Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome-arc

We are seeing a lot of OpenGL problems with our Android app running under ARC on either Chrome on the desktop or on Chromebook.

We use OpenGL ES1 for our drawing.  This same code works fine on iOS, Android and Mac.  However when running under ARC we see blank rectangles where our text should be.  Other drawing comes out at a vastly wrong scale.  There are lots of obscure OpenGL errors in the Logcat.

Are others having these problems?  I was wondering if it was because we are still using OpenGL ES1.

Answer (score 0):

ARC is still in Beta so I wouldn't expect things to run flawlessly. Try updating your graphics drivers. That should do the trick.

[https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=2nd+Generation+Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+Processors+with+Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics+3000%2F2000][1]

Comment: Seems unlikely to be a graphics driver problem.  This happens on several Macs running Chrome as well as two different Chromebooks.